# VB.net how to disable column header download

Tags: vb.net

Problem : I'm loading a csv file to dgv. There is a predefined column name that i set by UI design. Whenever i download this CSV file after loading into the dgv, it download the header repeatedly. Below is 2 photos.
[Before download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc3O9.png) and [After Clicking download 2times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jz5sn.png)

Here is my download button code

```
Private Sub btnDownload_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDownload.Click

    Dim oldFile As System.IO.FileInfo = New IO.FileInfo(filePath)
    oldFile.Delete()

    Dim headers = (From header As DataGridViewColumn In gridData.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn)() _
          Select header.HeaderText).ToArray
    Dim rows = From row As DataGridViewRow In gridData.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)() _
               Where Not row.IsNewRow _
               Select Array.ConvertAll(row.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).ToArray, Function(c) If(c.Value IsNot Nothing, c.Value.ToString, ""))
    Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter(filePath)
        sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", headers))
        For Each r In rows
            sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", r))
        Next
    End Using
    Process.Start(filePath)
End Sub
```

How can i stop this repeated header downloading?

Here is the upload csv file code:

```
Private Sub ReadCSV()

    gridData.Rows.Clear()

    Dim TextLine As String = ""
    Dim SplitLine() As String

    If System.IO.File.Exists(filePath) = True Then
        Using objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.ASCII)
            Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
                TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
                SplitLine = Split(TextLine, ",")
                gridData.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
            Loop
        End Using
    Else

        MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like your upload is including the heading into the data rows portion of the DataGridView. Then when the download occurs, it is being writtin to the CSV. Possibly the problem is in the upload portion of the code.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer i've added the upload code. whats wrong with you could you tell me

Comment: When you're reading the CSV, test the first line to see if it contains header elements or actual data. That should stop the header getting added to the DataGridView as the first row.

Comment: yea it gets read into the csv file and display on dgv